# How to play changing midi on Android - jetPlayer

Tags: java, android, midi

I have been breaking my head over this.

I have a ndk c++ app that continuously generates note info in a vector.

Now I need to either write this as midi files (from ndk or sdk) that can be played back without delay.

It seems I should use JetPlayer. But this is not documented properly, I cannot make heads or tails from it.

How do I get the .jet file? And where exactly is my midi info? I looked at the jetBoy example, but I don't really understand it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I am starting to think this is not possible with JetPlayer, because the jet file needs to be generated in advance (and the midi file is generated in the app). 
How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know JetPlayer can't generate midi.

So I used MediaPlayer instead and generated the midi with android-midi-lib.

Comment: Hi @dorien, do you have any written articles (or general notes) for how this audio project/research turned out? I'm currently beginning an audio (MIDI-based playback) project with Android (possibly) but I'm still in the early stages...

Comment: Yes, I have briefly described it in this paper: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=6595220&abstractAccess=no&userType=inst